# Creating a virtual keyboard in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have been using shiny for a while but not an expert. I searched the web and stackoverflow but no luck. I would like to create a simple textAreaInput widget in shiny but i would like small buttons at the bottom of the text widget which when pressed enters the text in the text area. Basically like a virtual keyboard. For e.g. one button would have a "pi" symbol and the other would have the "power symbol" so students can easily type in the text area using these keys.

Apologize for not having a working example as i did not have much success. There is a virtual keyboard in shiny "shinykeyboard" package but that does not work for me. Any help, links, directions would be very helpful.

Comment: There are existing tools for teaching math, for example desmos, and many others. Perhaps it would be easier to use them than to try developing your own tool, especially because you are obviously out of ideas for the moment.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion regarding Desmos but wanted to create something similar in shiny as i wanted to use some R packages to develop psychometric test.